# How to display title alone of this Languages object in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, arrayobject

My goal is to display all the titles of these objects in react native.

```
{
    "Languages": [
        {
            "PKM": "Languages",
            "Title": "Tamil2",
        },
        {
            "PKM": "Languages",
            "Title": "தமிழ்",
        },
        {
            "PKM": "Languages",
            "Title": "English",
        }
    ],
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Retrieve Success!"
}
```

The expected result is to display the three titles alone from these objects. I've seen using the js parse method but it displays only the single title not not the three.

Answer (score 0):

use map

```
const data = {
  Languages: [
    {
      PKM: 'Languages',
      Title: 'Tamil2',
    },
    {
      PKM: 'Languages',
      Title: 'தமிழ்',
    },
    {
      PKM: 'Languages',
      Title: 'English',
    },
  ],
  status: 'success',
  message: 'Retrieve Success!',
};
```

on render

```
{data.Languages.map((item) => (
  <Text>{item.Title}</Text>
))}
```

update code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const data = {
  Languages: [
    {
      PKM: 'Languages',
      Title: 'Tamil2',
    },
    {
      PKM: 'Languages',
      Title: 'தமிழ்',
    },
    {
      PKM: 'Languages',
      Title: 'English',
    },
  ],
  status: 'success',
  message: 'Retrieve Success!',
};

export default function App() {
  // const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1')
  //     .then((res) => res.json())
  //     .then((json) => {
  //       console.log(json);
  //       setData(json.Languages);
  //     });
  // });
  const renderItem = (item) => {
    return <Text>{item.item['Title']}</Text>;
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get
        a shareable url.
      </Text>
      <FlatList
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        data={data['Languages']}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a response from API using Flatlist. Is there any way to get the title using Flatlist?

Comment: yes, save it on variable, refer the flatlist to that table

Comment: I can able to get the complete response. In the flatlist renderItem ==>

<Text style={styles.name}>{item.Languages.Title}</Text> wasn't displaying.  But If I run {item.Languages[0].Title} can able to display first title. I need to display all the three titles.

Comment: wait, i'll update on the code, check now

Comment: Still, it wasn't displaying bro.

Comment: please share your code